# JPA - What if @Table is not specified for the entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I referred `@Table` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Table.html) and it states that:

> If no Table annotation is specified for an entity class, the default
>   values apply.

My question is what is the default value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default table name is the unqualified classname of the entityclass and the default schema name is the connected schema from the database connection.

Answer (score 5):

If you specify `@Entity` and you don't specify `@Table`, your class will be mapped and in the database you will get the class name as name for your table.

From [**Marking a POJO as persistent entity**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-entity) section in the documentation:

> **@Table** is set at the class level; it allows you to define the table, catalog, and schema names for your entity mapping. **If no @Table is defined the default values are used: the unqualified class name of the entity**.

For example if you have:

```
@Entity
public class MyTest{ ...
```

Your table will have the name `my_test` in your database. 
Note that PascalCase will be converted to pascal_case. Be aware of that.

Comment: +1 for pointing out to the right section of the Hibernate documentation. JPA documentation, which I quoted, was vague and left people guessing..